# testing smtp code without being blocked as spams

Tags: c#, email, asp.net-core, smtp, spam

I have a piece of code sending out account activation emails with a link in it using SMTP. My code connects to my mail box on an email provider and sends out mails. The first few mails went through. And then they started failing. Obviously they were blocked as spams.

My question is then how can I test my code? People suggest to alter the configurations of the mail server. But since I am using a 3rd party email provider, I have no control over it.

My website production server is on AWS but I can't use that for my testing.

Here is a snippet of my code. Pretty standard.

```
            using (var msg = new MailMessage())
            {
                msg.From = new MailAddress(From);
                msg.Subject = subject;
                msg.Body = body;
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                msg.To.Add(toEmail);

                string error = "";

                try
                {
                    using (var client = new SmtpClient(SMTPServer))
                    {
                        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SMTPUserName, SMTPPassword);
                        client.Send(msg);
                    }
                }
                catch (SmtpFailedRecipientException se)
                {
                    error = $"Unable to mail to {toEmail}";
                }
                catch (SmtpException se)
                {
                    error = "Mail server connection failed.";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    error = "Email failed";
                }

                return error;
            }
```

`SmtpException` is thrown and no mails are sent/received.
The `Subject` is `Blah blah Account Activation` and the `Body` is `Please use the following link to activate your account: <a href='blah blah blah'></a>`.

Comment: You need to configure the mailbox to not prevent anti spam measures assuming they are being triggered at the sender and not the recipient end. When you say you don't have control, if you are using a third party, someone must have control that you can speak to? I don't see any reason you wouldn't have some say unless you are using an SMTP relay without someone's permission/knowledge

Comment: When we develop code that sends emails we use SMTP4DEV locally

Comment: @Charleh There is no option for me to change those configurations. The only one available to me is whether to turn SMTP on of off. Some google results recommend to have some more info in DNS or something and that is why I said I have no control.

Comment: @CaiusJard When you guys go production, how can you make sure it still works with a real email provider?

Comment: Cos SMTP is a standard, we don't use anything complex that smtp4dev doesn't emulate and we log errors that let us pick up config/networking problems which is really all that could viably be wrong on prod. For sending mails my past co's have always used a send service like mailgun/sendgrid/authsmtp so really only host/port/user/pass to go wrong. occasionally for small tests or monitoring apps we use another hosting we pay for at a few $ per month. You'd be amazed how much easier stuff is with paid subs, when every spammer uses free services and those providers lock it down - for what we pay ...

Comment: ...in a basic business web hosting with email plan, couple of dollars a month, at your hourly rate of pay i'm sure even just getting stuck on and researching this issue will have cost you/your boss more than a year's hosting.

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks for your details. I will give that a try.